# Create a new column and assign values to the first row by each group in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing pandas dataframe below:

```
   id  time  c  d
0   1     1  2  3
1   1     3  1  6
2   2     2  3  2
3   2     3  8  6
```

I also have values stored in a list such as:

```
list = [0.4, 0.6]
```

I want to create a new column in the existing dateframe and assign each list element in the first row for each group (id) such as:

```
   id  time  c  d  new_col
0   1     1  2  3  0.4
1   1     3  1  6
2   2     2  3  2  0.6
3   2     3  8  6
```

Answer (score 3):

Group the dataframe by `id` and use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create a sequential counter, then use boolean indexing with `loc` to assign the list values where the value of the counter is `0`

```
lst = [0.4, 0.6]
df.loc[df.groupby('id').cumcount().eq(0), 'new_col'] = lst
```

---

```
   id  time  c  d  new_col
0   1     1  2  3      0.4
1   1     3  1  6      NaN
2   2     2  3  2      0.6
3   2     3  8  6      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary created by `enumerate` and set values only first per groups in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
L=[0.4, 0.6]

df["new_col"] = df['id'].sub(1).map(dict(enumerate(L))).mask(df['id'].duplicated())

print (df)
   id  time  c  d  new_col
0   1     1  2  3      0.4
1   1     3  1  6      NaN
2   2     2  3  2      0.6
3   2     3  8  6      NaN
```

---

```
L=[0.4, 0.6]

df["new_col"] = df['id'].sub(1).map(dict(enumerate(L))).mask(df['id'].duplicated(),'')

print (df)
   id  time  c  d new_col
0   1     1  2  3     0.4
1   1     3  1  6        
2   2     2  3  2     0.6
3   2     3  8  6
```

If possible any groups in `id`, e.g. `10, 20` use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
L=[0.4, 0.6]

df["new_col"] = (df.groupby('id').ngroup().map(dict(enumerate(L)))
                   .mask(df['id'].duplicated(),''))

print (df)
   id  time  c  d new_col
0  10     1  2  3     0.4
1  10     3  1  6        
2  20     2  3  2     0.6
3  20     3  8  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help solve your problem? (I can't see any benefit to only putting that value in the first occurrence of the group and not the other values)

```
mapping = {1: 0.4, 2: 0.6}

df["new_col"] = df['id'].map(mapping)
```

Result:

[image]

Note: If all of your ids are sequential integers starting at 1 and all of the values in your list are also in that correct order you could convert it to a mapping dict using:

```
mapping = {i+1: value for i, value in enumerate(your_list)}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.ngroup` with `numpy.take`:

```
l = [0.4, 0.6]
gid = df.groupby("id").ngroup()
df["new_col"] = np.where(gid.duplicated(), "",  np.take(l, gid))
```

Output:

```
   id  time  c  d new_col
0   1     1  2  3     0.4
1   1     3  1  6        
2   2     2  3  2     0.6
3   2     3  8  6
```

Explain:

The difficulty here is to apply only to the first row of each group.

Applying `duplicated` to the taken value is dangerous since it will remove values in another group should the values happened to duplicate (e.g. if `l == [0.4, 0.6, 0.4]`).

So `duplicated` is applied to `gid` to assert we extract the first row of each group.

- `df.groupby("id").ngroup()`: enumerates the group to create indices.
  Note that this is invulnerable to the type of `df["id"]`, such as `["a", "a", "b", "b"]`.

  In case `df["id"]` is always numeric and starts from `1`, you can replace this with

  ```
  gid = df["id"] - 1
  ```
- `np.take(l, gid)`: With the generated indices, take the list elements.
- `np.where(gid.duplicated, ...)`: To ensure the taken values from `l` is only applied to the first rows of each group (a.k.a. non-duplicates), and the rest gets filled with `""`.